# Cmake error: Not find package configuration file provided by QT5Svg

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, qt5

I first time build a CMake project. I installed QT5 and started building configuration using CMake. When the process starts, an error occurs immediately. Error logs are given below:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Svg" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5SvgConfig.cmake
    qt5svg-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Svg" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Svg_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Svg"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:111 (find_package)
```

I tried all solutions present over ubuntu, stack overflow, and other websites. I checked the path  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/` but there is no `Qt5Svg.config` file present. I installed the dependency of QT5SVG using the ubuntu command but the file does not exist in the CMake qt5 path. When I check QT5 dependencies installed on ubuntu there I found some packages related to QT5SVG. I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS os. Why did this issue happen?

Comment: You may need to install the Qt5Svg package manually as it is not contained in qt5-default package by using `sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev`. If that does not help, please add to your question how and what you installed from Qt5.